# Runtime exception: failure delivering result

Tags: android, android-activity

In answering this question please take into consideration the fact that I'm an Android newbie.

In my app **Activity A** explicitly calls **Activity B**, which has to supply it with some data from the user (i.e. a date). **Activity B** returns when the user presses the **Done** button.

But in the case that the user presses the **Back** button, what I get is a **Runtime exception failure delivering result**.

Any clue?

Comment: Could you post the code that is causing the problem please?

Comment: I don't even know what piece of code should I post...

Comment: If that's the case then I suggest that you first need to do some investigation to narrow down the scope of the problem.

Comment: What happens when an activity called in order to supply some results (i.e. to send back an intent) gets closed without sending back any intent?maybe that's the probelm

Comment: That's a much better question - and indeed, it's the one that's been answered below. Hope you now have something to go on!

Comment: @razlebe thanks for prompting me writing a better question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you need to check for a cancelled result in Activity A.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that even if I checked for resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK, it still got the error. I solved this by instead of doing:

```
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
 finish();
```

I had to do:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
finish();
```

I also had to add this approach to onBackPressed().

Answer (score 2):

Have you gotten familiar with the activity lifecycle yet? You'll want to make sure that everything is happening in the appropriate lifecycle method.  If, for example you are opening some type of media in onStart() and forget to close it in onStop(), you could run into a runtime exception.

It's hard to say exactly what the cause is without viewing the code, but I suggest reviewing the activity lifecycle and making any needed changes.  If you still have issues please give a code sample.  Logcat should tell you which line of code caused the exception, can you at least include that part?

See http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

[image: Android Activity Lifecycle]